# \centering\arraybackslash with an array environment?

Tags: arrays

The following code gives me an error:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem, array}
\begin{document}
{\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
{\setlength\itemindent{10pt}\item 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.5cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.5cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.5cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.5cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.5cm}}

\hline
x & l_{[x]} & d_{[x]} & l_{x+1} & \mathring{e}_{[x]} \\
\hline
\end{array}
\end{equation*}}
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

Note: for various reasons, I have to keep `minipage` there. For some reason, this code gives me an error when it compiles. It gives the following output:

[image]

The errors either say there is a `}` missing or a `$` missing. My eyes don't see such a thing!

Comment: `>{\centering\arraybackslash$}m{1.5cm}<{$}` is the correct input. However, `\arraybackslash` is really needed only in the last column. Why do you have braces around the minipage and also around the item? Of course the table will always start lower than the item, probably you already know it.

Comment: This is an excerpt from a much larger block of code. The reason why the braces are around the `\item` is to indent the entire `enumerate` environment. As for why the `minipage` is in braces, there is a `\hspace` that I've used that moves the entire minipage.

Comment: Neither pair of braces does anything good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only `l`, `c` and `r` columns in `array` are supposed to contain just math mode material, since paragraphs in math mode don't make much sense. However, you can state math mode in `p`, `m` or `b` columns by adding `$` to the specifications. Namely

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{
  >{\centering\arraybackslash$}m{1.5cm}<{$}
  >{\centering\arraybackslash$}m{1.5cm}<{$}
  >{\centering\arraybackslash$}m{1.5cm}<{$}
  >{\centering\arraybackslash$}m{1.5cm}<{$}
  >{\centering\arraybackslash$}m{1.5cm}<{$}
}
\hline
x & l_{[x]} & d_{[x]} & l_{x+1} & \mathring{e}_{[x]} \\
\hline
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
```

Actually, `\arraybackslash` is necessary only in the last column. It would be much easier adding

```
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash$}m{#1}<{$}}
```

to your preamble and specify the table as

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{ *{5}{M{1.5cm}} }
\hline
x & l_{[x]} & d_{[x]} & l_{x+1} & \mathring{e}_{[x]} \\
\hline
\end{array}
\end{equation*}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem comes from the blankline and the fact the m type columns are *not* in math mode. While I was at it, I simplified your code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage [english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{enumitem, array}

\begin{document}

{\begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*)]
{\setlength\itemindent{10pt}\item%
\begin{equation*}
\begin{array}{*{5}{>{\centering\arraybackslash $}m{1.5cm}<{$}}}
\hline
x & l_{[x]} & d_{[x]} & l_{x+1} & \mathring{e}_{[x]} \\
\hline
\end{array}
\end{equation*}}
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice. I suppose `*{5}` means to repeat the code afterward five times?

Comment: Exactly. I think it's defined in the `array` package.

Comment: I know this is old but actually, you don't need any package to use the syntax `*{x}{y}` to repeat `x` times the column defined by `y`.